# Why do mydropdown keep failling? Discord.js

Tags: drop-down-menu, discord, discord.js

This what my console shows:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined
at Object.execute (/home/runner/Bot/commands/rr1.js:99:5)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:2432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { MessageMenuOption, MessageMenu } = require("discord-buttons")
const { prefix } = require('../config.json')

module.exports = {
  name: 'rr1',
  description: 'send embedded level message',
  async execute(message, args) {
    const option1 = new MessageMenuOption()
      .setLabel("Black Charcoal")
      .setValue("Option 1")
      .setDefault()
      .setEmoji("")     
    const option2 = new MessageMenuOption()
      .setLabel("Love Magenta")
      .setValue("Option 2")
      .setDefault()
      .setEmoji("❤️")
    const selection = new MessageMenu()
      .setID("Selection")
      .setMaxValues(1)
      .setMinValues(0)
      .setPlaceholder("Select Role")
      .addOption(option1)
      .addOption(option2)
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("0x00a6ff")
      .setTitle("Colour Role")
      .setDescription(`<@&x>\n<@&x>`)
    const role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "x")
    const role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "x")

    async function menuselection(menu) {
      switch(menu.values[0]) {
        case "Option 1": 
          if(message.member.roles.cache.has("x") || message.member.roles.cache.has("x") || message.member.roles.cache.has("x")){
            await message.member.roles.add(role1)
            await message.member.roles.remove([role2])
            await menu.reply.send("Claimed Black Charcoal!", true)}
        break;
        case "Option 2":
          if(message.member.roles.cache.has("x") || message.member.roles.cache.has("782356910782677003") || message.member.roles.cache.has("780476718820884581")){
            await message.member.roles.add(role2)
            await message.member.roles.remove([role1])
            await menu.reply.send("Claimed Love Magenta!", true)}
        break;
      }
    }
    let menumsg = await message.channel.send(embed, selection)
    client.on("clickMenu", (menu) => {
      if(menu.message.id == menumsg.id) {
        if(menu.clicker.user.id == message.author.id) menuselection(menu)
        else menu.reply.send("You are not allowed to pick!", true)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Main.js

```
client.on('message', async (message, guild) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    switch (message.content) {
      case (prefix + "rr1"):
        client.commands.get("rr1").execute(message, args);
      break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your main file (the part where it starts with `client.on('message', message =>{` untill `}` ?

Comment: It marks this line ```client.on("clickMenu", (menu) => {```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```js
        client.commands.get("rr1").execute(message, args);
```

You're only giving the `message` variable and the `args` array, but not the `client` so you have two choices.

Either do include `client` on your execute function

```js
        client.commands.get("rr1").execute(message, args, client);
```

Or don't include `client` and just replace every single `client` on your command files with `message.client`

```js
    message.client.on("clickMenu", (menu) => {
```

If I was you I'll go with the first one but it's up to you

Comment: This code doesnt work in my code:
```client.commands.get("rr1").execute(message, args, client);```
But this code works at mine  ``` message.client.on("clickMenu", (menu) => {```

Comment: Perfect then ! Just do the same on every command